# Process ordinal data as a function of time in R

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance, ordinal-data

I try to treat ordinal data as a function of time in order to analyze if there is a significant difference between two different modalities.

Here is my data set

| num | Note | Semaine | Companion | mummies | mycosis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 13 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 13 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 13 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 13 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 31 | 5 | 13 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 14 | 0 | 3 | 2 |

num is the number of th plant, there are 30 plant in each modality so a total of 60 plants.

Note is the grade given according to the amount of aphid found on the plant :
1 "absence"
2 "founder"
3 "founder + larvae"
4 "colony"
5 "winged colony"

Semaine is the weak in which the statments were done

Companion is the modality
0 "without companion plant"
1 "with companion plant"

mummies is the grade given according to the amount of mummies found on the plant :
1 "absence"
2 "few"
3 "a lot"

I performed a linear regression using the polr function but time is taken into account here as a fixed factor.

```r
head(aphid, 2)
aphid$Note = factor(aphid$Note) 
e = polr(Note ~ num + Semaine + Companion, data = aphid, Hess = TRUE) 
n4 = data.frame(num = 30, Semaine = 14, Companion = 0) 
predict(e, n4, type = "probs") 
exp(cbind(OR = coef(e), confint(e)))
```

I want to find a way to see if there is a statistical difference between the number of aphids, mummies, mycosis and weeks of the two modalities. Is there a model that can do that ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "interpret" and "process"?

Comment: Hello, 

Yes, I want to find a way to see if there is a statistical difference between the number of aphids, mummies and mycosis of the two modalities.


Is there a model that can do that ?